# How to do pattern matching to a variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

So im creating a procedure that accepts an argument namee and returns all users whose name is a substring of namee

```
    create procedure search_res(IN namee varchar(50))
    begin
    select * from usr where name like %namee%;
    end
```

But im getting the following error.
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%namee%; end' at line 3.
What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to add quotations to `'%namee%'`?

Comment: adding quotes will match the word namee as such instead of the value inside namee.

Comment: Can you add sample data of  `usr` table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function

```
select * from usr where name like CONCAT('%',namee,'%');
```